# Problems with Testing Spring Boot Application with Multi Maven Project Setup

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, dependencies, spring-boot-test

I am currently running into some problems with spring boot and multi maven project structure. I am using Spring Boot 4.3.1.

My project structure looks as follows:

```
parent
-- pom.xml
-- application
   -- pom.xml
   -- src
      -- main
         -- java
            -- Application.java (annotated with @SpringBootApplication)
      -- test
         -- java 
            -- MyApplicationTest.java (annotated with @SpringBootTest)
-- library
   -- pom.xml
   -- src
      -- main
         -- java (...)
      -- test
         -- java
            -- MyLibraryTest.java (annotated with @SpringBootTest)
```

`application` module has a dependency on `library`.

`MyApplicationTest` works perfectly fine, but running `MyLibraryTest` instead, I fail with the following error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at  org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOr FindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:409)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:305)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
```

My first guess is that `library` needs a dependency on `application`, but this causes a cycle.

Is there any solution to that problem?
How can I structure my application correctly?

thanks a lot for suggestions.

`MyLibraryTest` looks as follow:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @Transactional
    public class MyLibraryTest {
       @Autowired
       private MyService service;

       @Test
       public void testMyService_Save() {...}

    }
```

Comment: do share the code of `MyLibraryTest` where you find the error. Also, make sure it has all required dependencies defined in its pom.(as already defined in the app -> pom.xml ) for `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084491/unable-to-find-a-springbootconfiguration-when-doing-a-jpatest shall help in that case. Could possibly be a duplicate of this itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `library` module's `pom.xml` includes -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

which is required for the module to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation. You might already be using the same in your `app` module but is not included in the `library` module.

---

Well post the Edit, found the question to be possibly a duplicate of [Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration when doing a JpaTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084491/unable-to-find-a-springbootconfiguration-when-doing-a-jpatest)

Also quoting from Thomas's answer from the same thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084906/1746118)

> The thing about `@DataJpaTest` and a few other annotations is that they
>   look for a `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotation in the current package,
>   and if they cannot find it there, they traverse the package hierarchy
>   until they find it.
>
> For example, if the fully qualified name for your test class was
>   `com.example.test.JpaTest` and the one for your application was
>   `com.example.Application`, then your test class would be able to find
>   the `@SpringBootApplication` (and therein, the
>   `@SpringBootConfiguration`).
>
> If the application resided in a different branch of the package
>   hierarchy, however, like `com.example.application.Application`, it would
>   not find it.

which seems to be the case for you, where you are trying to test an application in a different module itself. Hence the error that you see.

Comment: @user3278695 as commented previously as well, please edit the question and share the code for `MyLIbraryTest` to see further

Comment: So how would you fix this?